# JDialog GridBagLayout Not Producing the Look I Want

Tags: java, gridbaglayout, jdialog

I am trying to create a JDialog using GridBagLayout but I cannot get things looking the way I want. Am I perhaps using the wrong layout model? My code is:

```
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class alertDialog {

JDialog dialog=null;
private GridBagLayout layout=new GridBagLayout();
private NumberFormat tempFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();

public alertDialog(String type_,TimelineRecord timeLine_) {

    dialog=new JDialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Alert");
    dialog.setSize(600, 200);
    dialog.setLayout(layout);
    dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    Monitor mon=timeLine_.monitor;
    int row=1;
    JLabel msg=new JLabel();
    if (type_.equals("Temperature")) {
        msg.setText(mon.getName()+" temperature has been reached");
    }
    else {
        msg.setText(type_);
    }
    JButton dismiss=new JButton("Dismiss");
    dismiss.addActionListener(new delayButton(timeLine_,dialog));
    JButton delay5=new JButton("Delay 5 Minutes");
    delay5.addActionListener(new delayButton(5,timeLine_,dialog));
    JButton delay10=new JButton("Delay 10 Minutes");
    delay10.addActionListener(new delayButton(10,timeLine_,dialog));
    JButton delay15=new JButton("Delay 15 Minutes");
    delay15.addActionListener(new delayButton(15,timeLine_,dialog));
    dialog.add(msg,makeGbc(0,row++));
    dialog.add(dismiss,makeGbc(1,row++));
    if (mon!=null) {
        JLabel currentTemp=new JLabel("Current Temperature");
        JLabel newTarget=new JLabel("New Target");
        JFormattedTextField temp=new JFormattedTextField(tempFormat);
        temp.setText(Double.toString(mon.current));
        JFormattedTextField target=new JFormattedTextField(tempFormat);
        target.setText(Double.toString(mon.target));
        dialog.add(currentTemp,makeGbc(0,row));
        dialog.add(temp,makeGbc(1,row));
        dialog.add(newTarget,makeGbc(2,row));
        dialog.add(target,makeGbc(3,row++));
    }
    dialog.add(delay5,makeGbc(0,row));
    dialog.add(delay10,makeGbc(1,row));
    dialog.add(delay15,makeGbc(2,row));
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimelineRecord timeline=new TimelineRecord();
    new alertDialog("tod",timeline);

}
}
```

Here is the TimeLineRecord:

```
import java.util.Timer;

public class TimelineRecord {
// text of event to take place (Saved to XML)
public String eventText;
// time of day for alarm (Saved to XML)
public String tod;
// target temp for alarm (Saved to XML)
public double targetTemp;
// pit temp to change to (Saved to XML)
public double pitTemp;
// meat type
public String meat;
// weight of meat
public double weight;
// Average cook time for this probe in minutes  (Saved to XML)
public long avgCookTime;
// total cook time in minutes
public long totalCookTime;
// associated monitor instance (ID saved to XML)
public Monitor monitor=null;
// associated pit probe instance (ID saved to XML)
public Monitor pit=null;
// timer for alarm instance
public Timer timer=null;
// actual time of event
public String actualTod;
// actual temp at event
public double actualTemp;
// actual pit temp at event
public double actualPitTemp;
// Method to set variables
public void setObject(String obj_,String value_) {
    switch(obj_) {
        case "eventText":   eventText=value_;
                            break;

        case "tod":         tod=value_;
                            break;

        case "targetTemp":  if (!value_.equals("")) {
                                targetTemp=Double.parseDouble(value_);
                            }
                            break;

        case "pitTemp":     if (!value_.equals("")) {
                                pitTemp=Double.parseDouble(value_);
                            }
                            break;

        case "meat":        meat=value_;
                            break;

        case "weight":      if (!value_.equals("")) {
                                weight=Double.parseDouble(value_);
                            }
                            break;

    }
}
}
```

The Listener:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class delayButton implements ActionListener {

private int delay=0;
private TimelineRecord timeLine=null;
private JDialog dialog=null;

public delayButton(int minutes_,TimelineRecord timeLine_,JDialog dialog_) {
    delay=minutes_;
    timeLine=timeLine_;
    dialog=dialog_;
}

public delayButton(TimelineRecord timeLine_,JDialog dialog_) {
    timeLine=timeLine_;
    dialog=dialog_;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (delay==0) {
        System.out.println("Got dismiss for "+timeLine.monitor.getName());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Got "+Integer.toString(delay)+" minute delay for "+timeLine.monitor.getName());
    }
    dialog.dispose();       
}

}
```

And the GBC generator:

```
public static GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      Insets WEST_INSETS=new Insets(5,0,5,5);
      Insets EAST_INSETS=new Insets(5,5,5,0);
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;

      gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.BOTH
            : GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

      gbc.insets = (x == 0) ? WEST_INSETS : EAST_INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = (x == 0) ? 0.1 : 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      return gbc;
   }
```

The first line can be any length so I want it to be centered based on length. The button on the second line should be centered. Oddly, the height of the first button in the last line is different from the other buttons. They should all be the same.

[image: Resulting Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AlertDialog extends JDialog {

    public AlertDialog(Frame owner) {
        super(owner);
        createGUI();
    }

    public AlertDialog(Dialog owner) {
        super(owner);
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("My Label");

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        topPanel.add(label);

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        centerPanel.add(button, c);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        bottomPanel.add(button1);
        bottomPanel.add(button2);
        bottomPanel.add(button3);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
    }
}
```

and version with one panel

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AlertDialog extends JDialog {

    public AlertDialog(Frame owner) {
        super(owner);
        createGUI();
    }

    public AlertDialog(Dialog owner) {
        super(owner);
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("My Label");

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;

        add(label, c);

        c.gridy++;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;

        add(button, c);

        c.gridy++;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.weighty = 0.0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        add(button1, c);

        c.gridx++;

        add(button2, c);

        c.gridx++;

        add(button3, c);


        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
    }
}
```

in your code this resize first button on last row (x = 0)

```
  gbc.fill = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.BOTH
        : GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't thought of extending JDIalog and using multiple panels. I will have to spend some time studying this.

Comment: Well, it's also a panel, but it's harder to maintain. I have added an example.